# Issues with makefile and compiling. gcc error no such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compilation

```
make
gcc -o assn2 main.o Graph.o Agent.o Queue.o
gcc: error: Queue.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [assn2] Error 1
```

I am trying to make a file but Queue.o is missing. I can create this file with Queue.h and Queue.c but I don't know how to add this to my makefile.

I'e tried adding this to the makefile:

```
Queue.o : Queue.c Queue.h Item.h
```

but I don't know where to put it, and I've tried shoving it in there but it doesn't work. Can someone help me out please. Here is my current Makefile.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g

.PHONY: clean clobber

all: assn2 assn2Bonus

%o:%c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

assn2: main.o Graph.o Agent.o
    $(CC) -o assn2 main.o Graph.o Agent.o Queue.o

assn2Bonus: main.o Graph.o AgentBonus.o
    $(CC) -o assn2Bonus main.o Graph.o AgentBonus.o Queue.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o core

clobber: clean
    rm -f assn2
```

Comment: Your `assn2` target uses `Queue.o` but doesn't depend on it. Make have no way to know you need it to be built before linking.

Comment: I think I fixed it now ty